# Do if statements stop Javascript's threads?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, multithreading

I had a piece of code that appends some HTML to my page when an event is a triggered - an event specific to a plugin I am using. - and I had an `alert()` sitting there.

After I removed alert, my code did not work, as far as appending that element is concerned.

I came to find out that `alert()` does two things:

1. Pops the message supplied to it in a box
2. Halts the thread Javascript is using

[(link to where I found this information)](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-930002.html)

While I was scratching my chin to find a solution, an idea popped in my head, and it was to add this line where `alert()` was:

```
 if(1 == 1){}
```

an idea that supposedly solved a segfault error, demonstrated in JsConf at youtube in this [video](https://youtu.be/oCPT3L33848?t=1222)

to my suprise, it worked!
So, why did it work? do `if` statement actually stop the thread javascript is using?

**Code**:

I am using the jQuery plugin , [daterangepicker](http://www.daterangepicker.com).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('input[name="daterange"]')
    .daterangepicker({ /* options */ })
    .on('hide.daterangepicker', function (ev, picker) {
      if (elementExists) {
        var name = $(this).attr('name');
        var pickedRange = $(this).val();

        if (notAppended) {
          if (1 == 1) {
            //
          }
          $('input[name="someinputname"]')
            .parent('.form-group')
            .append(
              '<div class="row"><br /></div>' +
              '<div class="row messages">' +
              '<div class="col-lg-8">' +
              '<div class="alert alert-info">' +
              '<p class="small">blablabalba</p>' +
              '</div>' +
              '</div>' +
              '</div>'
            )
            .find('.row.messages')
            .fadeOut(20000);
        }
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: It would be better if you actually posted your code.

Comment: Need more info. Could you add the code your working with ?

Answer (score 1):

No, an `if` statement does not stop Javascript thread execution.  The `if` statement is evaluated and one branch or the other of code execution is selected based on the result of the `if` statement and code execution continues.  There is no pause.

`alert()` and `prompt()` are special cases of host functions (as does synchronous Ajax) that do halt the JS thread of execution until they are finished.  Regular Javascript statements such as `if` statements do not halt execution.

If, as the referenced thread mentions, installing an `alert()` somehwere fixes some problem in Javascript, then there is some wrong Javascript code that is being worked around by changing a timing issue.  For example, if one is trying to access the result of an asynchronous Ajax call before the result is ready, sometimes inserting an `alert()` will "accidentally" fix the problem by delaying the main JS thread until the async result is actually ready.  This is not a recommended solution, just a side effect of inserting an `alert()`.  The correct solution would be to fix the way the code is fetching the asynchronous result to be reliable without the `alert()`.

The segfault in the video is likely a flawed language implementation that gets accidentally worked around by changing the sequence of coding statements.  It is not a sign of anything intended in the Javascript language.

---

If you are serious about understanding why adding:

```
if(1 == 1){}
```

changed your program in any way, then you will HAVE to show the relevant code (probably in something we can actually execute) so we can analyze what is really going on.

Comment: @HamzaOuaghad - and what was the problem that was solved by adding the `if` statement?

Comment: The element I was appending did not get appended, as described in my question.